# How to replace the full content of a node using any xml lib?

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse a xml file using Python but I have some tags that might contain xml data. For example:

```xml
<code>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</code>
```

I want to write CDATA tags like this:

```xml
<code><![CDATA[
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ]]>
</code>
```

I tried (with lxml):

```
a = etree.fromstring(data)
for e in a.findall("code"):
    e.text = etree.CDATA(etree.tostring(e))
```

But I get:

```xml
<code><![CDATA[<code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?></code>]]>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</code>
```

Comment: Where is your problem? Afaict your example works flawless.

Comment: I just want to replace all the node's content by the same content but with CDATA tags arround.

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement code finds the `<code>` element and serializes it as the new text of the element.  It seems like you want to include only the *children* of the `<code>` element, though.

Try setting `e.text` to `CDATA(e.text)` instead of to the result of serializing `e`.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm the OP i registered after posting)

With 
    e.text = etree.CDATA(e.text)

I get

```
<code type="php"><![CDATA[
]]><?php echo $foo;
?>
</code>
```

for

```
<code type="php">
<?php
    echo $foo;
?>
</code>
```

Comment: Because e.text contains only plain text and not all the full node's content.